# Error in foreignkey table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench, workbench

I created the database structure using MySQL workbench. When I do the forward engineer or synchronize model it displays some errors.
When I remove the foreign key or if I connect **"INT"** as a foreign key to the second table then it's working fine. But I want to use **"Varchar(255)"**. Can't we use **"Varchar(255)"** as a foreign key? If so please help me to fix this error. I can't do forward engineer to this table.[image]

Comment: Yes u can use varchar as foreign key. There is no such constarint

Comment: where's your other part of foreign key in `personal_detail` table? you know, the second column?

Comment: @MridulKashyap In register table "id" is the primary key. In personal_details table "reg_id" is foreignkey but when i do forward engineer its showing an error.

Comment: @Naruto  yes I made the register table "id" as unique and its working fine. But I want to know if we use the foreignkey from another table, does it should be a primary key or unique key from that table? is it a must?

Comment: @acmsohail Unique constraint is must. Primary key is preferred.

Comment: I'm a bit unclear why you've tagged this with phpMyAdmin since you're using MySQL Workbench and the question doesn't appear to be related to phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use varchar as foreign key.It is appropriate to add a unique index or a unique constraint to your table. However, your primary key should generally be some "meaningless" value, such as an auto-incremented number or a GUID.